# How do i retrive recent unread messages(which are in inbox before folder gets opened). I want to read them once folder get's opened

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap, spring-integration-dsl

I'm just trying to read the unread email's from Gmail using IMAP. So when I run my application is able to read all the unread email's. Even though those emails are already available in INBOX before I ran my application. Here is the problem let's say I have 120 emails my application started reading them, and it already read one of it and count reduced to 119, then if suppose my email got another email then my service started processing that, and the remaining 119 emails will be the unread state and my application is not processing them

I have tried with DefaultSearchTermStrategy which is coming from Spring

```
    EmailReadTaskRunner<SampleMailMessage> emailTaskRunner = new 
    EmailReadTaskRunner<SampleMailMessage>();
        for (MailConfig mailConfig : yamlConfig.getMailConfig()) {
            if (mailConfig.isImapEnabled()) {
                Properties properties = this.getImapProperties();
                properties.put("mail.debug", 
                    String.valueOf(mailConfig.isDebugEnabled()));
                ImapMailReceiver receiver = new 
                ImapMailReceiver(mailConfig.getImageStoreUri() + 
                    "/INBOX");
                receiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
                receiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
                receiver.setJavaMailProperties(properties);
                receiver.setJavaMailAuthenticator(
                new MailAuthenticator(mailConfig.getUser(), 
                    mailConfig.getPassword()));
                StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows             
.from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter(receiver).shouldReconnectAutomatically(true)).handle(message -> {
            emailTaskRunner.read(emailReadTask, message, mailConfig);
                    }).get();
                this.getFlowContext().registration(flow).register();
    }
}
```

I want to read all unread email's, which can be recent or old.
Am Using SpringIntegration 5.0.3 version, And also using IMAP Protocol as I have mentioned in the code. I also want to know why it is showing this kind of behavior. Until new email comes to Gmail it is able to read them all, whenever a new email comes to Gmail it started reading new email's and ignoring previous unread email's

Comment: Your question is not clear. Set the javamail property `mail.debug` to `true` to see the IMAP interactions.

Comment: I can't tell what you're really doing from the code above.  Make sure you're looking for messages without the SEEN flag set, as opposed to messages with the RECENT flag set.